# iOS Facebook SDK searching for users with Graph search

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new to Graph Search, and I want to search for a user with an email address. Is that possible? Right now, I only know how to search with their name, like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=chandler+de+angelis&type=user&access_token={access_token}
```

I have an email address, and I need to check if there is a Facebook account with the same email address. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Simply put: This is not possible.

Comment: Is there any other Facebook API I can use to do this?

Comment: No. There is no such API

Comment: Thanks, @ChandlerDeAngelis , Your question had my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32622958/3411787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is from Facebook themselves. In post at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/335452696581712 a Facebook dev says

> The ability to pass in an e-mail address into the "user" search type
>   was removed on July 10, 2013. This search type only returns results
>   that match a user's name (including alternate name).

That's Facebook's new rules.