# Facebook SDK, Is it possible to fetch all users by username?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api

In my new project, client need that if he pass any name then it will give you list of all users(i.e. their public profiles).

I saw in [Graph API for User data.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user)

That is states that I can get user details by user-id like this,

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                           initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id}"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                  id result,
                                  NSError *error) {
// Handle the result
}];
```

But what if I want to fetch all users by username only, like facebook does in it's search controller?

For example If I pass `Steve Jobs`, then It will give list of all users named `Steve Jobs`.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22441340/3411787)

I can get all user's by user name only, here is an example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Steve+Jobs&type=user&access_token={access_token}
```

This will give me JSON of all users with named `Steve Jobs`.